# SQL min(), max()

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I have a table with price history for products(ProductCostHistory).
Columns: ProductID(PK,FK), StartDate(PK), EndDate, StandardCost, ModifiedDate

This is what the table looks like:

```
ProductID   StartDate   EndDate     StandardCost    ModifiedDate
707         2011-05-31  2012-05-29  12,0278        2012-05-29
707         2012-05-30  2013-05-29  13,8782        2013-05-29
707         2013-05-30      NULL    13,0863        2013-05-16
708         2011-05-31  2012-05-29  12,0278        2012-05-29 
708         2012-05-30  2013-05-29  13,8782        2013-05-29
708         2013-05-30  NULL        13,0863        2013-05-16
```

For each product I want to view: Current Price, the highest and the lowest historical price.

This is my Code:

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
SELECT Distinct ProductCostHistory.ProductID, ProductCostHistory.StandardCost, MAX(ProductCostHistory.StandardCost) AS HighestPrice, MIN(ProductCostHistory.StandardCost) AS LowestPrice FROM Production.ProductCostHistory
GROUP BY ProductID, StandardCost
Order by ProductID
```

Output looks like this:

```
ProductID   StandardCost    HighestPrice    LowestPrice
707         12,0278         12,0278         12,0278
707         13,0863         13,0863         13,0863
707         13,8782         13,8782         13,8782
708         12,0278         12,0278         12,0278
708         13,0863         13,0863         13,0863
708         13,8782         13,8782         13,8782
```

But I want it more like this (example):

```
PRoductID    StandardCost    HighestPrice     LowestPrice
707          13,0863         13,8787          12,0278
708          12,0278         13,8782          12,0278
```

Thanks

Comment: Why for product 707 you want MAX StandardCost and for 708 MIN? Is there any rule for that?

Comment: Why is ProductCostHistory in the select but not in your output?

Comment: The name of the table is ProductCostHistory. I want to know 3 things for each product. 1: Current price. 2: The highest price this product ever had in history. 3: The lowest price this product ever had in history

Comment: How is the "Current price" determined?

Comment: @CarlDecks How is current price determined? For the `productid` 707 you choose the middle row, and for  708 you choose first row (of 708)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I've edited the question

Comment: Current price should be determined by EndDate = null, I guess?.

Comment: How is 12,0278 the current price for 708 which ended on `2012-05-29`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a conditional aggregate for *CurrentPrice*:

```
SELECT h.ProductID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN h.EndDate IS NULL THEN h.StandardCost END) AS CurrentPrice,
       MAX(h.StandardCost) AS HighestPrice, 
       MIN(h.StandardCost) AS LowestPrice 
FROM Production.ProductCostHistory h
GROUP BY h.ProductID
ORDER BY h.ProductID
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm struggling with a beginner course in SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way... select the current record and then join to a min/max subquery on product ID.

```
select p.ProductID, p.StandardCost, g.MaxPrice, g.MinPrice
from ProductCostHistory p
inner join (select ProductID, MAX(StandardCost) as MaxPrice, MIN(StandardCost) as MinPrice
            from ProductCostHistory group by ProductID) g
  on g.ProductID = p.ProductID
where p.StartDate <= GETDATE() AND (p.EndDate > GETDATE() OR p.EndDate IS NULL)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c6d9a/1)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is including Product.StandardCost outside of an Aggregate function.

Do you need the 2nd column in your requested desired output? I could understand it's use if you took an average but in the current example I don't think it makes sens to include it?

This should work:

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
SELECT ProductCostHistory.ProductID, MAX(ProductCostHistory.StandardCost) AS HighestPrice, MIN(ProductCostHistory.StandardCost) AS LowestPrice 
FROM Production.ProductCostHistory
GROUP BY ProductID
Order by ProductID
```

************ **EDIT** ************

With the further info you supplied about the start table the following will do what you require:

```
WITH CTE_AggregatePrices AS
(
  SELECT ProductID
    ,  MAX(StandardCost) AS HighestPrice
    ,  MIN(StandardCost) AS LowestPrice 
  FROM ProductCostHistory
  GROUP BY ProductID
)
SELECT PCH.ProductID
    ,  PCH.StandardCost
    ,  CAP.HighestPrice
    ,  CAP.LowestPrice
FROM ProductCostHistory AS PCH
INNER JOIN CTE_AggregatePrices AS CAP ON PCH.ProductID = CAP.ProductID
WHERE PCH.EndDate IS NULL;
```

Ok so what I've done is use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to get the aggregates you require (MIN & MAX prices), I like CTE's because they are simple and easy to read, but they are not always the best way forward, however in this case it fits the bill nicely.

So with the MIN AND MAX figures isolated against each **ProductID** it's simply a case of grabbing the the current price which based upon your data example is a simple WHERE clause that checks if the **EndDate** is NULL. We join the results of this to the aggregate CTE by the **ProductID** which allows us to show Current Price with the Highest and Lowest Price for a product.

As this is an assignment please take the time to check that this is what was being asked of you and that you understand what is taking place. For example if your course hasn't covered CTE's yet I doubt very much they are looking for this answer even though it is valid. You could get the same result using a subquery:

```
SELECT PCH.ProductID
    ,  PCH.StandardCost
    ,  CAP.HighestPrice
    ,  CAP.LowestPrice
FROM ProductCostHistory AS PCH
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ProductID
    ,  MAX(StandardCost) AS HighestPrice
    ,  MIN(StandardCost) AS LowestPrice 
  FROM ProductCostHistory
  GROUP BY ProductID
) AS CAP ON PCH.ProductID = CAP.ProductID
WHERE PCH.EndDate IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes I need current price as well. Current price is detarmined by EndDate = null I guess?. It's part of an assignment for school

Comment: @CarlDecks Ah that extra info makes all the difference. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

if you include standardcost in your query's select part , it will return all entries.

I think below query should be work for you

SELECT productid ,  MAX(StandardCost) , MIN(StandardCost)  FROM ProductCostHistory
GROUP BY productid